# Ansible: Capture single value from each element in dict

Tags: dictionary, ansible, return

I want to extract a list of users created with the following method:

group_vars/users.yml

```
add_users: "{{ users_all }}"
users_all:
  - name: bob
    create_home: yes
    shell: /bin/bash
    password: "{{ bob_user_pass | password_hash('sha512', bob_user_pass_salt) }}"
    state: present
  - name: jane
    create_home: yes
    shell: "/bin/bash"
    password: "{{ jane_user_pass | password_hash('sha512', jane_user_pass_salt) }}"
    state: present
```

play_create_users.yml

```
    - name: Create Users
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        create_home: "{{ item.create_home }}"
        shell: "{{ item.shell }}"
        password: "{{ item.password }}"
        state: "{{ item.state }}"
      loop: "{{ add_users }}"
      register: user_config
```

user_config

```
{
  - user_config: {
    - msg: All items completed
    - results: [ 
      - {
      - name: bob
      - state: present
      - move_home: False
      - password: NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD
      - changed: False
      - home: /home/bob
      - shell: /bin/bash
      - failed: False
      - item: {
        - name: bob
        - create_home: True
        - shell: /bin/bash
        - password: $6$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        - state: present
      }
      - ansible_loop_var: item
    }
      - {
      - name: jane
      - state: present
      - move_home: False
      - password: NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD
      - changed: False
      - home: /home/jane
      - shell: /bin/bash
      - failed: False
      - item: {
        - name: jane
        - create_home: True
        - shell: /bin/bash
        - password: $6$xxxxxxxxxx
        - state: present
      }
      - ansible_loop_var: item
    }
     ]
    - skipped: False
    - changed: False
  }
}
```

I can get a single result with:

```
    - debug:
        var: user_config['results'][0]['name']
```

```
{
  - user_config['results'][0]['name']: bob
}
```

Could anyone assist with a method of getting the list of created usernames? I have tried a few methods of iteration over the "user_config" variable without success.

The idea is to get a list that can be used as a loop value in subsequent tasks.

Cheers.

Comment: `user_config.result | map(attribute='name')`

Answer (score 0):

This answer was provided in a comment by @β.εηοιτ.βε.

Create a new fact containing the list of users.

```
    - name: Create User List
      set_fact:
        user_list: "{{ user_config.results | map(attribute='name') }}"
```

Use the new fact in a play.

```
    - name: Print User List
      debug:
        msg: "{{ user_list }}"
```

Gives the following result from the example above.

```
{
  - msg: [ 
           - bob
           - jane
          ]
}
```